# ICommentable interface in EF Code First - best practise

Tags: c#, interface, ef-code-first

Suppose I have multiple unrelated object (classes) where I can not get common abstract class for (and therefore unique primary key for all such classes). I would also like to apply list of common objects to all such classes (say for example list of Comments). My first approach would be something like this:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CommentContent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICommentable CommentableObject { get; set; }
}

public interface ICommentable
{
    ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Page : ICommentable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PageContent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Post : ICommentable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

What EF code-first did, was creating single `Comments` table, with multiple nullable Foreign Keys (one for each related class) : `Page_Id`, `Post_Id`.

One of alternatives is to have separate Comments table for each class: `PageComments`, `PostComments`.

Is there any other more elegant solution to this common scenario ? Which one of two alternatives above is better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're talking about an IsA (Is-A, Is A) relationship here. Your options are here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

they are essentially ways of mapping an is-a inheritance/implementation to an is-a database relationship. The second option (Table per Type) seems to do that in a way that is normalized, the third option I'm unfamiliar with.

In your case, if you're sure there will only be 2 ICommentable classes, you may want to stick with what you have. This will also allow you a bit more flexibility if you change your mind about them both implementing the same interface. Normalize 'till it hurts, denormalize 'till it works.

Comment: I will have to have much more than two ICommentable classes. As I mentioned, I will have to leave abstract class inheritance ("is-a") for something "more important" on some ICommentable classes. I am just fine with the first approach, but somehow I don't like multiple nullable FK keys in there, especially if there will be 8-10 ICommentable classes (and that number of nullable FKs).

I was thinking about new column - Unique Key (unique for all ICommentables) applied to each ICommentable class, but couldn't find similar approach.

Comment: I believe the unique key solution (he uses Owner) is what is described in the Table Per Class model in the article. If you take a look at it (and take a bit for it to sink in), it should provide some code to make Linq to EF queries a little easier. Don't be fooled by the nulls at the bottom of the page, they are from JOINed queries.